# Issues with Date/Time Picker in FlutterFlow

Tags: flutterflow

I created a date-time picker so that users can select events based on a certain date. But the page goes blank whenever I select a date.

The date-time picker is not filtering the events as I want it to. The filter I used was startTime (of the event) must be equal to the datePicked. The data for startTime comes from FireBase.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.